# Using MS Access to import multiple text files

Tags: ms-access, vba, text-files, ms-access-2013

I have about 600 text files with headers, and I don't really feel like importing them one by one manually into MS Access.

I don't want to append the text files into one Access table. If I have 600 text files, I want the result to be 600 Access tables.

I've searched high and low for this, the closest I've come is some code that would take my text files and append them into one access table. I don't want that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider a For/Loop VBA using the [DoCmd.TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) command that iterates through all text files in a folder directory and imports them with suffix to denote 1-600.

```
Dim FSO as Object, objFolder As Object, objFile as Object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Path\To\TextFiles")

i = 1
For each objFile in objFolder.Files
  If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "File_" & i, objFolder & "\" & objFile.Name, True
  End if
  i = i + 1
Next objFile

Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

In the empty argument in TransferText you can use a pre-defined specification object which you create during one manual import of the text file. This allows you to name fields, define data types, etc. of the imported text file.

Finally, if all files are structured the same, consider again importing into one table and use queries by relevant fields to break up in the 600 groupings if needed. To use one table, simply replace the `"File_" & i` argument above with a table string name: `"dataFiles"`. You save on table namespaces, storage from less database objects, and overall helps in better organization as well as the relational model.

Comment: I put this in a module, and couldn't get this to run - so I added the private sub and end sub to the code. (I don't really know VBA). Anyway it's giving me run time error 91 Object variable or With block variable not set. When I debug, it doesn't like that 2nd line that starts with FSO.

Comment: See update, those objects must be `Set`. And yes drop the code behind a command button of a form (which is a Private Sub) or put code in a module as a Sub or Function, then call it with some type of event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that you need to break the process in three steps

1st code that imports text to a table 
http://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/access_import_text_files.htm

Every text gets imported to a temp tables...
Then you examine the table fields

2nd code that creates tables
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=213261

3rd erase contents of temp table and proceed with the next text...or  when you import them you could add info in the temp table...like text name and process them afterwards in a batch

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()

        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        blnHasFieldNames = True

        strPath = "C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\test\"

        strTable = "Table1"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile
              DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, _
                TableName:="Test1", _
                FileName:=strPath & strFile, _
                HasFieldNames:=True
              strFile = Dir()
        Loop


End Sub
```